# Direction field of an autonomous system of 2 ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> An autonomous system of two ODE consists of two first order DE $x'=f(x,y)$ and $y'=f(x,y)$.

[image]

Is there a specific characteristic that i should look out for?

For instance, for first order autonomous ODE, the solutions are invariant under horizontal translation, which shows that the directed line segments at a certain $y_{0}$ has the same slope for all $t$ in the direction field.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same question. It's 5. All. Basically, if each point points towards 1 direction, it is an autonomous system.

Comment: Please expand your answer so that the explanation is clearer.